# Типизация ассоциативного массива

Tags: typescript, типы, typescript-типы

```
userData: {
  19: {
    key: 'some Value',
  },
  20: {
    key: 'some Value',
  },
  21: {
    key: 'some Value',
  },
};
```

с бэкенда приходит такая структура, как это типизировать?

Comment: `Record<number, { key: string }>`

Answer (score 0):

нашел такое решение:

```
interface keyI {
  key: string;
}
interface response {
  [key: number]: keyI;
}
```